# Selecting rows from a pandas DataFrame that isn't assigned to a variable

Tags: python, pandas

Complex row-selection expressions are done by creating a boolean series and passing it into the `[]` operator, eg:

```
df_usa_2018 = df[(df.Year == 2018) & (df.Country == 'USA')]
```

However, this requires the dataframe to have been assigned to a variable. Is there a shortcut for filtering a dataframe expression without assigning it? What I'm looking for is basically a function like

```
df_usa_2018 = pandas.read_csv(...).select(Year = 2018, Country = 'USA')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) with change `=` to `==` and `&` instead `,`:

```
df_usa_2018 = pandas.read_csv(...).query("Year == 2018 & Country == 'USA'")
```